# How to set default value in a checkbox field upon creation if that same checkbox in all records is set to false?

Tags: apex, trigger, administration, checkbox, default-value

I have a custom object in my org. I also have a checkbox labeled as Active. I need the checkbox to have a default value when I create a new record only if:

1. The Active checkbox are false in all records of my custom object
2. No records existing yet in my custom object

How can I do this? Apex isn't working here because it's not visible to the UI when New create button is click in Custom Object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a before save flow

Go to Setup -> Home tab -> Flows in quick search
Create a new Flow. Select Record-Triggered Flow. Specify your object name, set

- Trigger the Flow When: A record is created
- Optimize the Flow for: Fast Field Updates

There, first, add Get Records to find the records of your object with filter Active = true, how many records = all records

Second, an assignment to store the count into a variable

Third, a decision if count is 0 or not

If count is 0 - leads to another assignment

Fourth, Assignment: put in your `{!$Record.Active__c}` value True

Answer (score 1):

I can only think on using screen flows or custom lightning components the standard creation tool cannot do these queries to check this logic.